# PHP PayPal integration - Cancel link in approval e-mail

Tags: php, paypal

I need some help with PayPal integration.

I use this library:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Composer

and I use WebHooks to receive notifications of payments.

I create payment link like this:

```
        $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
                new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_client_id, $paypal_client_secret)
        );

        $apiContext->setConfig([
            'mode'=>$paypal_mode
        ]);

        $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
        $amount->setTotal('1.00');
        $amount->setCurrency(Config::get('paypal.currency'));

        $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);

        $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(Uri::create(Config::get('paypal.redirect_url')))
                ->setCancelUrl(Uri::create(Config::get('paypal.cancel_url')));

        $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale')
                ->setPayer($payer)
                ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
                ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

         $payment->create($apiContext);
         $payment_url = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Then, I run this link, log in to PayPal and make a payment.

Now, I receive WebHook with event PAYMENTS.PAYMENT.CREATED - so, OK, but after several minutes I get an e-mail:

"Would you like to complete your PayPal payment at xxx?
To finish, go back to xxx and give your final approval."

And text „give your final approval” is linked to my Cancel Page witch I entered into setCancelUrl() metod.

I don’t receive any more webhooks.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/

You have reached step 3, the payment was created and approved.

You are apparently missing step 4 to actually execute the payment and create a PayPal transaction.... so, no money has moved yet.

---

Moreover, all of the above and your work so far with the PayPal-PHP-SDK is for an old version of the PayPal REST API, `v1/payments`. I recommend setting all of those things aside and instead trying out the new v2/orders PHP SDK: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

Here is a demo pattern of the best UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Here is a reference for the server-side integration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/